# Convert an element to a string

Tags: reactjs

How can I convert a React element to a string:

```js
const e = React.createElement;

const _notification = e(
  "div", null, e(
    "button", null, "Foo"
  )
);
```

I need this:

```js
const notification = someReactMethod(_notification);
console.log(notification);  // => "<div><button>Foo</button></div>"
```

Note: I can't use Node.js anymore (this is way I'm using React).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use Node.js to build?

Comment: I can build in Node.js if there aren't alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the static methods of [ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup). Either `renderToString` or `renderToStaticMarkup`.

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
const notification = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(_notification);
// or
const notification = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(_notification);
```

The latter is recommended for static pages, the former is needed if the markup is to be hydrated into an app on the client.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't need to build it: I've found it here https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js